# Rcpp Armadillo: RStudio says "exp" is ambiguous

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, rcpp

I'm trying out Rcpp / RcppArmadillo in RStudio with the following code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using std::exp;
using std::log1p;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec log1pexp(arma::vec x) {
  for(int ii = 0; ii < x.n_elem; ++ii){
    if(x(ii) < 18.0){
      x(ii) = log1p(exp(x(ii)));
    } else{
      x(ii) = x(ii) + exp(-x(ii));
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

RStudio says the calls to `exp` are ambiguous. I've tried calling `std::exp` in the code instead of `using std::exp` but have no success. The code compiles without warnings through `Rcpp::sourceCpp('filename.cpp')`. If I cast `(float)x(ii)` in the code the warning disappears, but not if
 I cast `(double)x(ii)`.

Any insight appreciated, I'm pretty inexperienced with both C++ and RStudio.

**Picture of what's going on**

[image]

Comment: When you say, *"RStudio says"*, are you talking about the code diagnostics messages in the IDE? Or are you getting an actual compiler error?

Comment: At any rate, I would advise against using an unqualified `exp`, as (based on the declarations in the above code) this could refer to either `exp` the `std::` namespace or `exp` from the  `Rcpp::` namespace (and possibly the C function `exp` from `<math.h>`).

Comment: Thanks @nrussell. The code compiles without errors. It's the IDE that gives this diagnostic message.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, which version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: I *was* using 0.99 something, and, indeed, the messages are gone after updating. Want to write an answer stating the problem doesn't reproduce in newer versions so I can accept it?

Comment: You should probably just write up the answer and mark it accepted, since you have all of the information. Just make a note of the RStudio version you upgraded to in your answer.

Comment: For me, the issue was an undefined variable given to exp, and Rstudio complained about the "exp" instead of the undefined variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, don't do

```
using namespace Rcpp;
using std::exp;
using std::log1p;
```

If in doubt, be explicit.  Your code then becomes

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec log1pexp(arma::vec x) {
    for(size_t ii = 0; ii < x.n_elem; ++ii){
        if(x(ii) < 18.0){
            x(ii) = std::log1p(std::exp(x(ii)));
        } else{
            x(ii) = x(ii) + std::exp(-x(ii));
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

and compiled without a hitch (after I also changed `int` to `size_t` for the loop) -- and without an issue in the RStudio IDE (using a fairly recent daily, 1.0.116).

There are

- `std::exp()` in the standard library, using `double`
- `Rcpp::exp()` from Rcpp Sugar, using our vectors
- `arma::exp()` from Armadillo using its vectors

and I always found it easiest to be explicit.

*Edit:* I had missed `log1p`. Prefixing it with `std::` also requires C++11.  Two changes made.

Comment: Thanks for accepting.  Re-reading, I think a case _may_ be made that it was an IDE bug.  You did declare `std::exp` via the `using`, yet got warned.  Oh well.  My "better safe than sorry" advice still holds.

Comment: Yep, it's actually turned up again even in the new IDE version. If I copy-paste your code there, RStudio says use of exp is ambiguous again. I'll just follow your advice and be explicit, and ignore the RStudio message.