# Rcpp warning: Call to 'exp' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am writing a Rcpp code as below:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

 double ks(const double k, const double alpha, const double  mag, const double M0){
    double ksres;
    ksres=  k* std::exp ( alpha*(mag-M0) );
    return(ksres);
    }
```

.

But it shows that "Call to 'exp' is ambiguous". Why do I get this message and how will I solve it?

While I get in sessionInfo():

```
        R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
        Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
        Running under: OS X 10.12.6 (unknown)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.12.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.4       inline_0.3.14    gtable_0.2.0     rstan_2.9.0-3   
 [8] gridExtra_2.2.1  ggplot2_2.1.0    grid_3.2.4       munsell_0.4.3    stats4_3.2.4
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It compiles without errors. Please provide more information about your system, i.e., `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Why did you include both "cmath" and "math.h"? Especially with "using namespace std" afterwards.

Comment: @Roland Please see the edits

Comment: @teivaz what's your suggestion then? I am new in Rcpp. any suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: @gultu My suggestion would be to figure out what headers you need and why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rcpp Armadillo: RStudio says "exp" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997722/rcpp-armadillo-rstudio-says-exp-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this to be closed or deleted by OP. The question simply exhibits some allowed-but-not-recommended C++ usage:

- extra headers included: the math headers *are* already brought in by Rcpp (which is brought in by RcppArmadillo)
- you never ever need *both* `cmath` and `math.h`, and as stated here you do not need either
- we generally recommend against flattening all namespaces unconditionally

With this, your code looks like this (still containing a call for C++11 which is not used, but does no harm):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double ks(const double k, const double alpha, const double  mag, const double M0){
    double ksres;
    ksres=  k* std::exp ( alpha*(mag-M0) );
    return(ksres);
}

/*** R
ks(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
*/
```

This compiles without any warning whatsoever on my box (with stringent compiler warnings turned on, output not shown here) and runs as expected too:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/soQ.cpp")

R> ks(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
[1] 0.135335
R>
```