# Why do I get ambiguous errors in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, ambiguous, exp

While I have used macOS 10.14, everything worked fine. Then I updated to macOS 10.15.7, and now when I compile my Cpp code in the R environment, I constantly get the following error:

```
call to `exp` is ambiguous
```

The same occurs for other functions, such as `pow`.
I read that it depends on the input variables; however, I've never experienced anything similar before.

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646986/rcpp-warning-call-to-exp-is-ambiguous